# JQuery Hidden / Visible Error

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm newbie at Jquery. I want to make floating menu at my web site. I created div which is id="item"

Below code is in my .php file also I want to activate item after pressing my button which is id='sidebarOpenfile'.

```
<div id="item" style="float:left">
<?php include("leftmenu.php"); ?>
</div>
```

and my 'sidebarOpenFile' code is here

```
  <button id="sidebarOpenfile" class="toolbarButton" title="Toggle OpenFile" tabindex="5" data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar_openfile">
              <span data-l10n-id="toggle_openfile_label">Toggle OpenFile</span>
            </button>
```

Also My .php file has viewer.js file and .css file.

I wrote my .js file this code

```
document.getElementById('sidebarOpenfile').addEventListener('click',function() {
    alert("Its working"); // For sure whether event is working or not working,
 This code works and gets alert

$("#item").css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Also I wrote my .css file this codes

```
#item {
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:orange;
    left:0px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Normally, After pressing button It changes item's css visibility from hidden to visible. But It seems not working and does not effect.

For any helping I'll be appreciated.

Comment: Also, If I changes initial value from hidden to visible. Our div appears at left side.

Comment: You probably want to use `display: block/none;`. If you set the visibility the item is still there you just can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

For toggling visibility on click it's as easy as it can get. You don't need any pure javascript, just a (very) little jQuery:

```
<script>
  $('#sidebarOpenFile').click(function() {
  $('#item').toggle(); });
</script>
```

The toggle() function toggles the display state of the queried `#item`.

To just hide or just show you can use:

```
 $('#sidebarOpenFile').click(function() {
   $('#item').show(); // or $('this').hide()
}
```

For the sakes of convention, it should be wrapped in a self-invoking anonymous function like:

```
(function(){
  $('#sidebarOpenFile').click(function() {
  $('#item').toggle(); });
})();
```

Comment: If I use $('#item') my web site does not work. It only works document.getElementById('sidebarOpenfile').

Comment: It sounds like you aren't properly sourcing in the jQuery library. Make sure you are linking it in (either locally or via google) before your code.

Answer (score 1):

OK... I'll bite... first problem is the:

```
document.getElementById('sidebarOpenfile').addEventListener()
```

It is far easier in JQuery to just reference this with $('#sidebarOpenfile'), for starters...  but the real problem that I am having is that I can't find 'sidebarOpenfile' anywhere in the rest of your code; the id of the div you appear to be trying to effect is 'item', not 'sidebarOpenfile'.

This might very well be your issue.

The other possibility is that you actually have the proper id in the php code, which you didn't display.

**UPDATE**

Ok... my bad, not enough sleep.. you were tight, the id is there, and in the correct place.

```
$('#sidebarOpenfile').click(function(){$("#item").css('visibility','visible')});
```

This *should* work... but will only display the element.

If you wish it to toggle, you have to add a little extra:

```
$('#sidebarOpenfile').click(function()  
{
    if ($('#item').css('visibility')=='hidden')
    {
        $('#item').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#item').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
 });
```

Comment: İf I use such as $('') code which is different from  document.getElementById. My jquery doesn work. It seems If there is a any solution, Solution must be related document.getElementById. Also My SidebarOpenFile code is
    <button id="sidebarOpenfile" class="toolbarButton" title="Toggle OpenFile" tabindex="5" data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar_openfile">
                  <span data-l10n-id="toggle_openfile_label">Toggle OpenFile</span>
                </button>

Comment: My bad, you are right... stupid and tired, I didn't even look at the button!  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like:

```
$('#item').fadeToggle("fast", "linear"); //this will toggle the visibility back and forth and do it gradually
```

or

```
 $('#item').removeAttr('visibility');  //this will simply remove the visibility attribute thus making it visible by default
```

Comment: İf I use such as $('') code which is different from  document.getElementById. My jquery doesn work. It seems If there is a any solution, Solution must be related document.getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#item').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle element's visibility property with this simple jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var item = $('#item');
    $('#sidebarOpenfile').click(function() {
        if (item.css('visibility') == 'visible') {
            item.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        } else {
            item.css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });
});
```

[jQuery fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaUZR/) vs [javascript fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaUZR/1/)